# Why is my Material Design collapsible list expandable animation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, material-design, materialize

I'm using material design on my website and I have a sort of comment section made up by a collapsible list. I want the user to be able to open several comments by setting the collapsible mode to 'expandable'. It does what I want but the sliding animation to open a new comment does not work. It just displays the comment whitout any animations. But if you want to close it (by clicking it), it slides perfectly up again.

So it slides up (when closing), but not down (when opening).

Example: the expandable list at the bottom of [this](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) page.

As you can see, I have a collapsible list which is expandable. (I'm using Razor to dynamiclly set content)

## View:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header">
                //Comment preview and date here...
            </div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                //Display comment text etc here...
            </div>
            
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And this js initialization is in the document ready function. I've tried to change accordion to 'true' and then all the animation works perfectly. I also tried to set 'expandable = true', but I'm sure if that is a thing.

## Javascript:

```
$('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false 
});
```

I really appreciate any help. This is my task for exam so it's a bit important :)

Comment: Did you make sure you have the proper link to the cdn script?

Comment: If I understood you right, the javascript is correctly linked. This is a very complex project and we use js a lot and all functionality is working. Except for this piece with the expandable list.

Answer (score 0):

The manual/example is really clear. Firstly: when your js is running? It's inside a doc ready event? And if You check out the example the content of the li is divided into header and body. Your example miss that.

Comment: Yeah, the js init is running inside the document ready and the li have content, I just didn't show it, but I've updated it now so you can get a better picture of the situation.
Actually, I tried it without the javascript initialization and it behaves the same way. Any further suggestions?